# Specifying result MIME type when querying GraphDB via Javascript (RDF4J Server REST API)

Tags: javascript, ajax, mime-types, graphdb

I'm trying to query a GraphDB repo using Javascript. Here is the code:

```
var SPARQLendpoint = {

    getData: function (query) {

        var endpointUrl = 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/myRepo',

            settings = {
                headers: { Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json'},
                data: { query: query },
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            };

        $.ajax(endpointUrl, settings).then(function (data) {
            $('body').append(($('<pre>').text(JSON.stringify(data))));
            console.log(data);
        });

    });

    }

}
query = 'here is the query';
SPARQLendpoint.getData(query);
```

But I get this error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:7200/repositories/myRepo?callback=jQuery321005935533972872964_1529595202948&query=...'
>   because its MIME type ('text/csv') is not executable.

If I inspect the request via Chrome's developer tools, I can see the expected CSV-serialized resultset under the Application tab(!?)

Is there a way for telling GraphDB/RDF4J to serialize the resultset as a JSON or to manage such a CSV serialization in the ajax request?

Comment: i think you should try setting `contentType` header to `application/json` or something suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by starting graphDB with `-Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.enable=true` and removing  `dataType: 'jsonp'` from the JS code